# Name that entity (3)

Tags: riddle, word

We are dotted around and what all life need
for structure, stability and to feed

Some share the name of what we hold
others bear the names of characters of old

Nomads we fear will make us stray
or Dwarves will decide to take us away

Our shape is manipulated by those greater than us
we only survive untill they make a fuss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> A planet.

We are dotted around and what all life need for structure, stability and to feed

> Everything we know is built on a planet, including ourselves.

Some share the name of what we hold others bear the names of characters of old

> Some are named after things we can hold (Mercury, Earth), others after characters (Pluto).

Nomads we fear will make us stray

> Nomads in this case are bodies in space (asteroids etc.) that could substantially alter our course or damage the planet irreparably.

or Dwarves will decide to take us away

> Dwarves are known for digging too greedily and too deeply.

Our shape is manipulated by those greater than us

> A planet's shape is determined by its own gravity which is, of course greater than us.

we only survive untill they make a fuss

> And if you believe mass media we're slowly destroying our planet through industry...

Comment: I really enjoyed the links you made, pluto is not something i originally thought of but saying gods would of made it childs play. Dwarves also an awesome link thought i was thinkin of white dwarfs that go supernovae and destroy neigbouring planets.

Comment: White Dwarves aren't planets, though, they're stars. Pluto was, of course, Mickey Mouse's dog.

Comment: @Psychemaster, the dwarves aren't  the planets in the riddle, they take away the planets.

Comment: @Mew Just realised that. **facedesk**